# Monkeypatching inner import

Tags: python, python-decorators, monkeypatching

I have 3 files (using py2).

a decorator:

```py
# decoratorfile.py
def deco(func):
   return func
```

a class using the decorator:

```py
# classfile.py
import decoratorfile
class Cla:
    @decoratorfile.deco
    def meth(self):
        pass
```

and a file using the classfile:

```py
# excecution.py
from classfile import Cla
cla = Cla()
cla.meth()
```

I want to monkeypatch the decorator and I can edit only the `execution.py` file.
How do I do so?

Answer (score 0):

Just monkeypatch the `deco` function *before* the class `Cla` is defined (but after you `import decoratorfile`). The following collapses your example into one file but spreading it out over multiple files shouldn't affect the result if you follow the previous sentence.

```
from functools import wraps

def deco(func):
   return func

def monkey_patch(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def with_print(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Hi")
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return with_print

deco = monkey_patch # decoratorfile.deco = monkey_patch
class Cla:
    @deco
    def meth(self):
        pass
cla = Cla()
cla.meth()
```

Output

```
Hi
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I can only edit `execution.py`.

Comment: @Jochman See my other answer; I'll leave this one up just in case this solution would fit another person's needs.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a hack but you could just rewrite the `import decoratorfile` to effectively import the monkey patched `deco` decorator.

```
$ cat monkeypatch.py 
import decoratorfile
from functools import wraps
def monkey_patch(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def with_print(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Hi")
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return with_print

decoratorfile.deco = monkey_patch

$ cat execution.py 
import inspect
import classfile
import monkeypatch

classfile_source = inspect.getsource(classfile)
monkeypatch_source = inspect.getsource(monkeypatch)
exec(classfile_source.replace("import decoratorfile", monkeypatch_source))

cla = Cla()
cla.meth()

$ python3 execution.py 
Hi
```